# The point of writting this isomorphism theorem like this?

Tags: group-theory

In group theory there is this isomorphism theorem that doesn't seem to give any special information the way it is written.

> Let $T\unlhd G$ and let $S\leq G$ then $\frac{S}{S\cap T}\cong \frac{TS}{T}$

The part that I don't understand is why say $\frac{S}{S\cap T}\cong \frac{TS}{T}$ and not $\frac{S}{S\cap T}\cong \frac{S}{T}$ since $\frac{S}{ T}\cong \frac{TS}{T}$.  The way this is written make me read it like $9=1*3^2$ rather than $9=3^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $S/T$ makes no sense unless $T$ is a subgroup of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

The motivation for this is to have a group of which $T$ is a (normal) subgroup. This makes the formulation of the result nicer in that it depends less on the ambient group $G$.